# What is the appropriate way to use subquery aliases?

Tags: sql, subquery, alias

Why does the following subquery alias work

```
Select Top 1 Salary From 
(Select Distinct Top 3 salary From Employee Order by salary)
result
Order by salary
```

but this one produces a syntax error

```
Select salary From Employee
Where salary < (Select Max(salary) From Employee)
result
Order by salary
```

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*?

Comment: it says syntax error @GMB

Comment: Is there no more information than syntax error? Have you tried the second statement without "result"?

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near 'result'." This is all there is @h.m.i.13

Comment: So have you tried to remove 'result' from your query?

Comment: @Estif: It does not make sense to give an alias to the subquery in the second query. The subquery is just there to return a scalar value, that is used in the `where` condition. Hence the error. Just remove that alias.